# Splitting field and monomorphism

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I've come across such theorem in Galois theory.

Let $F$ be an algebraic extension of field $K$. $F$ is a splitting field over $K$ of a set of polynomials in $K[x]$ iff for every $K$-monomorphism of fields $σ: F \to N$, where $N$ is any splitting field over $K$ containing $F$, we have $σ(F)=F$.

The sketch of proof of one direction is as follows.
Let $u$ be a root of $f_i$, which is in the set of polynomials in $K[x]$. $σ(u)$ is also a root of $f_i$. Since $σ$ is an injection, it must simply permute the roots of $f_i$. $F$ is generated over $K$ by all the roots of all the $f_i$, whence $σ(F)=F$.

My question: is the condition of $N$ being a splitting field necessary? Can we replace $N$ by any extension of $K$ containing $F$? (It seems every step in the proof above has nothing to do with $N$ being a splitting field)

Comment: The key step that the other roots of $f_i$ are also elements of $F$ absolutely needs the fact that $F$ is a splitting field. A standard counterexample is $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $F=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$, $N=\Bbb{C}$. We have a $K$-homomorphism that maps $\root3\of2$ to $\omega\root3\of2$ where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ is a third root of unity. In this case both $\root3\of2$ and $\omega\root3\of2$ are roots of the polynomial $x^3-2$, irreducible over $K$.

Comment: That example has been covered many times on our site already. In various guises. Did you search? (Not saying that it would be immediately obvious which buzzwords give the desired hits).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what I mean is $N$, the larger field being a splitting field($\Bbb{C}$ in your example). Whether it has some polynomials solved but not completely solved doesn't seem to affect what we do on $F$...

Comment: In that example $\sigma(F)=\Bbb{Q}(\omega\root3\of2)$. This is a different field from $F$ because $F$ only consists of real numbers whereas $\omega\root3\of2\notin\Bbb{R}$. A splitting field $N$ contains all the zeros of any irreducible $f(x)$ (over $K$) polynomial such that $N$ contains at least one of the zeros of $f(x)$.

Comment: In the example case the irreducible polynomial is $f(x)=x^3-2$. That has three zeros in $N$, and $\sigma$ would be forced to permute them. But only one of its three zeros is in $F$, so  what's there to permute? Still $\sigma$ can map that zero, $\root3\of2$, to another number $\in N$, but $\notin F$.

Comment: The difference to, for example $F=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$, comes from the fact that there we have a homomorphism $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2$. However, because $F$ is a splitting field $-\sqrt2$ is also an element of $F$. In the cube root case the other roots are not in $F$. Yet they are in a homomorphic image of $F$.

Comment: Yet in other words. Because the claim concerns all $K$-homomorphisms $\sigma: F\to N$, we have the freedom to go outside of $F$. The upshot is that when $F/K$ is a splitting field we cannot.